# How to loop through array of layers in mapbox to listen for a click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, mapbox

I am newbie to Mapbox API and I am trying to develop something in which geojson files are returned from the server and the features are plotted on the map.

I am successful in plotting features on the map. What I do is look through all records and see if the geojson column has a value and if it does I fetch it from the server, make a new layer and plot it on that layer.

These are all polygons. What I need to do is to fire an event when I click on one of the polygons which is why I am using individual layers. Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        L.mapbox.accessToken = 'someKey';
        var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'someMap')
            .setView([-39.67, -69.26], 4);

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('header h2').text('Equipment Map');

            $.getJSON('distributor-companies', function (data) {
                var layers = [];
                $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                    if(item.geojson != ''){
                        var file = item.geojson;
                        layers[i] = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);
                        $.getJSON('/geojson/' + file, function(data){
                            console.log('layer' + i);
                            layers[i].setGeoJSON(data);
                        });
                    }
                });
                $.each(layers, function(i, item){
                    console.log(item);
                    // item.on('click', function(e){
                    //  alert('hello');
                    // });
                });

                layers[32].on('click', function(e){
                    alert('hello');
                });
                layers[31].on('click', function(e){
                    alert('hello hi');
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Now I take all the data from the distributor-companies route and make a new layer each time and plot data for every record. So at the end I am left with a lot of polygons.

In the end I am trying to individually register a click event listener on the layers which is working perfectly. But the code just before that where I am trying to loop through the layer is not working. The console.log function is showing me all the layers as object but when I try to register an on click event on the item it doesn't work and my console says TypeError item is undefined but console.log is working fine with it.

Clearly I am not a JavaScript expert and don't realize what am I doing wrong. I just need to loop through all the layers and place an onclick event on them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to add each feature as a separate featureGroup, it does that for you. Just instanciate the featureGroup with a GeoJSON featurecollection object:

```
var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer(geojson).addTo(map);
```

Then loop over added features, which are in fact just layers and add the onclick event to them:

```
featureLayer.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    layer.on('click', function (e) {
        // here e.target holds the layer
        // and e.target.feature holds the actual feature
        alert('Clicked layer ID: ' + e.target.feature.id);
     });
});
```

It's a simple as that. Working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/31nQWnEnDYzNSmroZB8G?p=preview

If you want to keep it like you've got you can just do the above in your code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('header h2').text('Equipment Map');
    $.getJSON('distributor-companies', function (data) {
        var layers = [];
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            if (item.geojson != '') {
                layers[i] = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);
                $.getJSON('/geojson/' + item.geojson, function (data) {
                    layers[i].setGeoJSON(data);
                    // Loop over the added layer
                    layers[i].eachLayer(function (layer) {
                        // Add click event
                        layer.on('click', function (e) {
                            // Do stuff
                            alert('Clicked layer ID: ' + e.target._leaflet_id);
                        });
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

If you want to work with just one featureLayer you could do something like this:

```
// Add empty featureLayer
var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);

// Get URL index
$.getJSON('index.json', function (index) {
  // Create empty feature array
  var features = [];
  // Loop over URLs
  $.each(index, function (i, url) {
    // Fetch GeoJSON from URL
    $.getJSON(url, function (geojson) {
      // Push GeoJSON to array
      features.push(geojson);
      // Check if is last URL
      if (i == index.length - 1) {
        // Call addFeature with array
        addFeatures(features);
      }
    });
  });
});

function addFeatures (features) {
  // Set features in featureLayer
  featureLayer.setGeoJSON(features);
  // Loop over layers in featureLayer
  featureLayer.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    // Attach click handler
    layer.on('click', function (e) {
      // Do stuff
      alert('Clicked layer ID: ' + e.target.feature.id);
    });
  });
}
```

Here's a working on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/dIMn9oiSpfsltq4iiilq?p=preview

Comment: But how would I make this work in my case. You see, in your example you have all the features stacked in one geojson file. On the other hand I have multiple files coming in with the geojson, each having a polygon in it. How do I make it work then because I am looping already and plotting the geojson so wouldn't the featureLayer variable change each time? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So if i understand correctly, each file holds a GeoJSON featurecollection containing one (or more) features? Or an array with one (or more) features?

Comment: Each file contains one feature actually. Basically these are distributors accross a country uploading their territory. So each file has a polygon in it.

Comment: I've added two pieces of code, one if you want to keep it like you've got it. (untested but should work) The other shows you how to combine all those features into one featureLayer with a working example. Hope that helps.

Comment: One small thing, what do I do if I have to change the color of the polygon? Can I do it while setting the geojson or will have to code it in the geojson itself?

Comment: How to remove a layer or all layers at once?

Comment: No thanks, you're always welcome, this is what SO is for. Accepting the answer is more than enough :) About your two new questions, this is not what the comments are meant for, they're for clarifying the question/answer not for asking completely new questions. I think it's best you combine those two into a new question so that others can help too and people can find the question and answer(s) when searching. Keep things more clear and less confusing over here on SO. I'll keep an eye out for your new question. Good luck!